# How to fix error I get in ARIMA model script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arima, python-3.9

Well I have to create ARIMA mathematical model for United States GDP forecast. Although I corrected and rechecked almost every line of the script I continue getting this error message. 2 version of the script and error message:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s8DdF_jANqtq6EFlUKgOykv6bpQ_4deUx13LvDIRCrk/edit?usp=sharing

Please help, show where is my mistake and what I ought to do to fix it